# Paypal Mobile SDK getting Error

Tags: iphone, paypal

i have a application in Appstore which worked well. But from few days i am not getting any payments but orders only. So i downloaded the sample app and new sdk from paypal and used my sandbox accounts to test it. But when i run those using my client_id and email its having Error call Platform Error in my device and in simulator its saying System error.

I attached the screen shot of the error here

can any one please say whats the error ? .. is it mine or paypal .

[image]

Comment: Do contact to paypal...

Comment: From what I can tell at first glance, this error is thrown because the email account of the receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to receive payments.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert chathu87@gmail.com its my developers test account. Original account is from Australia. App is based from Australia. So thats not the problem. Because its did receive payments until last week. And it suddenly stopped.

Comment: That's what that error code (539041) links to though. Can you file a ticket with us at https://www.paypal.com/mts? We'll investigate this further and discuss with you directly. Please share the ticket number here once created. Thanks!

Comment: #130724-000462 this is the reference number i got after i submitted the question ≥.. hope you will help me to overcome this issue.
thanks